# Increment a function in R using a closure (recursively add a function constructed using a closure to an existing function)

Tags: r, recursion, functional-programming, closures, perceptron

I'm trying to create a function `w(t)` from some data. I do this by looping through the data, creating a function, and adding this to `w(t)`. I'm running into infinite recursion problems that arise because I don't know when R is evaluating variables. The error message I get is:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too
>   deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Below is an example of a Kernalised Perceptron. I generate some linearly separable data and try to fit it. The functional addition occurs in the function `kern.perceptron` where I:

1. Create a function from the data: `kernel <- FUN(x, ...)`. From the call this translates to creating a function `function(t) (x %*% t)^3` where x should be *evaluated*. (I think this is where I may be falling down).
2. add/subtract this function to the existing function `wHat`

How can I correctly update the function such that `wHat(t) = wHat(t) + kernel(t)`?

```
prepend.bias <- function(X){
    cbind(rep(1, nrow(X)), X)
}

pred.perc <- function(X, w, add.bias=FALSE){
    X <- as.matrix(X)
    if (add.bias) X <- prepend.bias(X)
    sign(X %*% w)
}

polyKernel <- function(x, d=2){
    # Function that creates a kernel function for a given data point
    # Expects data point as row matrix
    function(t){
        # expects t as vector or col matrix
        t <- as.matrix(t)
        (x %*% t)^d
    }
}

pred.kperc <- function(X, w, add.bias=FALSE){
    X <- as.matrix(X)
    if (add.bias) X <- prepend.bias(X)
    as.matrix(sign(apply(X, 1, w)))
}

kern.perceptron <- function(X, Y, max.epoch=1, verbose=FALSE, 
                            FUN=polyKernel, ...) {
    wHat <- function(t) 0
    alpha <- numeric(0)
    X <- prepend.bias(X)
    bestmistakes <- Inf
    n <- nrow(X)
    for (epoch in 1:max.epoch) {
        improved <- FALSE
        mistakes <- 0
        for (i in 1:n) {
            x <- X[i,,drop=F]
            yHat <- pred.kperc(x, wHat)
            if (Y[i] != yHat) {
                alpha <- c(alpha, Y[i])
                wPrev <- wHat
                kernel <- FUN(x, ...)
                if (Y[i] == -1){
                    wHat <- function(t) wPrev(t) - kernel(t)
                } else{
                    wHat <- function(t) wPrev(t) + kernel(t)
                }

                mistakes <- mistakes + 1
            }
            else alpha <- c(alpha, 0)
        }
        totmistakes <- sum(Y != pred.kperc(X, wHat))
        if (totmistakes < bestmistakes){
            bestmistakes <- totmistakes
            pocket <- wHat
            improved <- TRUE
        }
        if (verbose) {
            message(paste("\nEpoch:", epoch, "\nMistakes In Loop:", mistakes,
                          "\nCurrent Solution Mistakes:", totmistakes, 
                          "\nBest Solution Mistakes:", bestmistakes))
            if (!improved)
                message(paste("WARNING: Epoch", epoch, "No improvement"))
        }
    }
    return(pocket)
}

set.seed(10230)
w <- c(0.3, 0.9, -2)
X <- gendata(100, 2)
Y <- pred.perc(X, w, TRUE)
wHat <- kern.perceptron(X, Y, 10, TRUE, polyKernel, d=3)
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you actually want to do.  Making a *function* from *data* doesn't make sense.  If you want to apply derived data to a function, consider adding input arguments to said function. As it stands, you haven't shown us what is "working," whether you got any error messages, etc.

Comment: Making a function from data: the data `x` defines what the function will be. `polyKernel` creates a function from a datapoint `x` and the option `d`. I'll add error message to the question though the example code should reproduce the error.

Comment: It would be more helpful to work on producing a *minimal* working example, that exhibits the problem you are facing.

Comment: @RusanKax, that's fair. I will do so when I have some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your getting a stack overflow because your createing a more and more deeply nested function `wHat`.  You could keep a registry of kernel functions in a closure as in:

```
LL  <-  local({
    #initialize list of kernel functions in the closeure
    funlist = list()
    #a logical vector indicating whether or not to add or subtract the kernal functio
    .sign = logical(zero)


    #register a kernal function and it's sign
    register <- function(fun,sign,x){
        funlist<<-c(funlist,list(fun))
        add<<-c(add,sign)
    }

    # wHat uses k in the closure without having to pass it as an argument
    wHat <- function(t){

        out = 0
        for(i in seq(length(.sign))
            if (.sign[i]){
                out <- out + funlist[[i]](t)
            } else{
                out <- out - funlist[[i]](t)
            }
    }
    list(wHat,register)
})

wHat  <-  LL$wHat
register  <-  LL$register
```

then to register a kernal functions you call

```
register(KernelFun,sign)
```

and when you call

```
wHat(t)
```

you get the sum of the kernel functions in the registery, which I think is what you want.

Incidentally, you could do this without closures too...

Comment: Thank you for your efforts here. It doesn't quite solve the problem as I'm not multiplying kernel functions together, I'm adding them. Additionally, the kernel function is constructed using the data point `x` and the closure `polyKernel`.

Comment: Edited so that wHat is a sum of kernel functions

Comment: you can register the `x` values just like you register the `sign`.   This is just a model of how you can do what you want (to add a series of kernel functions) without nesting functions